# How mature is clojure-clr? Can I use it with Mono?

Tags: .net, clojure, clojureclr

How mature is [clojure-clr](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr)? Does this support all the functions that clojure/jvm provides? Does it run on Mono without any problem?

I tried clojure-clr, and it seems to work fine with REPL. However, when I tried to run examples with `mono Clojure.Main.exe clojure/samples/ants.clj`, I got a bunch of error messages. Is this a problem with running clojure-clr on Mono?

Comment: Wiki (https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr/wiki) does only say "ClojureCLR is usually a little behind the JVM implementation". No detailed state... In which I'm interested a lot so +50pts from myself. Where it lags, where it is up to date, what is buggy and what is done?

Comment: The ants sample explicitly uses Java-only GUI libraries, so it's no surprise whatsoever that it won't work on other backends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is commonly used from, what i gather, on mono though it gets less attention than clojure-jvm in almost every way so it seems reasonable to expect it to lag the JVM version on features and have its own set of bugs. Slower development may also reduce the bug creation rate perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I find this SO post quite interesting and useful - [Clojure on the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445042/clojure-on-the-clr)

This video clip is also pretty interesting - http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/charles/emerging-langs-clojure-and-f, and from this video, Rich Hickey (the inventor of Clojure) said that Clojure was initially programmed with C# and Java. He also mentioned the original name he thought about Clojure was CLJ(C#, Lisp and Java): [Why is Clojure named Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427128/why-is-clojure-named-clojure)