# Why is Clojure named Clojure

Tags: clojure, jvm

Why is the name of the language, "Clojure"?

I googled a bit, asked in #clojure. So far, no luck.

Comment: Closure + Java/JVM surely.

Comment: I'm really curious about what the people in #closure said :)

Comment: [01:00] <jebberjeb> why is clojure named clojure?

[01:02] <amalloy> jebberjeb: closures, in java? *shrug*

Comment: Yeah but "Clojure" is more catchy than "A modern Lisp for the JVM". You're overthinking this.

Comment: Exactly, you are grossly overthinking this. Even the angled "j" in the official logo should hint at closure + java.

Comment: You two underthought it -- tsk.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Rich Hickey's (He's the designer of Clojure) comment on that is the 1st reference link on wiki:

> *Did you pick the name based on starting with the word "closure" and 
>   replacing the "s" with "j" for Java?
>   It seems pretty likely, but it  would
>   be nice to have that confirmed.*
>
> The name was chosen to be unique. I
>   wanted to involve c (c#), l (lisp) 
>   and j (java).  Once I came up with
>   Clojure, given the pun on closure, the
>   available  domains and vast emptiness
>   of the googlespace, it was an easy 
>   decision.

http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/766b75baa7987850

Comment: Indeed. Microsoft screwed up Google with C#. Come on I'm a C developer!

Comment: The most screwed up name of the language is in my oppinion: IO :)   Cant find sh** when you need something.

Comment: @ticking: you still don't get much anyway!

Comment: Searching on "io-lang" or "iolang" or "iolanguage" seems to get plenty of relevant hits.  Google rather cleverly hacked Googlespace for their own new language by clearly recommending that postings and queries related to their newly endorsed language use "golang."  It'll do until we have a properly "semantic web" and true ontological disambiguation is ubiquitous.